# Secure way to use pem file on app engin

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to implement a service that will return a signed URL to a client
Im using this code as reference [signing-code-go](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#signing-code-go) .

Im thinking to  upload the file as use the app.yaml to serve it to the application only  something like that .

```
- url: /files
 static_dir: files
```

What will be the best and secure way to use the **pem** file inside the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Static files" **are** served to users, as https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers makes it clear.  To quote from this URL:

> If you have data files that need to be read by the application code,
>   the data files must be application files, and must not be matched by a
>   static file pattern.

With this approach, you'll just upload the `.pem` together with the rest of your application and read it from your code as a local file.